# UI distortion when displaying multiple image thumbnails on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, ios-4.2

I want to display thumbnail images on a view.
I am using following method to add an image to thumbnails. Images are taken from the database

When I add a single image, everything works fine. But if I call this method in a loop to add multiple images, strange things happen (UI gets distorted and some part of screen goes black, not only for this application even for home screen)

On the simulator, everything works fine even if I add many images.

Does anyone have any idea, where I am going wrong? am I missing out something?

```
-(void)addImageThumbnailOnViewWithImageData:(NSData *)imgDataToBeAdded{

    UIImageView *imgView;

    imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tempX, tempY, 70, 70)];

    tempX+=80;
    if (tempX>300) {
        tempX=10;
        tempY+=80;
    }

    UIImage * newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgDataToBeAdded];
    [imgView setImage:newImage];

    [self.view addSubview:imgView]; 


    [imgView release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView *imgView;

imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tempX, tempY, 70, 70)];

tempX+=80;
if (tempX>300) {

```
tempX=10;

tempY-=80;//i think u have to modify this with -
```

}

UIImage * newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgDataToBeAdded];

[imgView setImage:newImage];

[self.view addSubview:imgView];

[imgView release];

}

Comment: Can you explain why? since this code works very well on simulator, I don't think so there is any problem with X and Y values

Comment: u have added image frame with from upwards by +.here i have corrected them